# Compare command substitution string not null in fish

Tags: fish

I'm trying to test if a git repository has the `showuntrackedfiles` option set to `no`.

My first aproch was:

```
if test (git config --get status.showuntrackedfiles) = no 
    echo "hi"
else
    echo "bye"
end
```

but this breaks if `showuntrackedfiles` is not set.

```
test: Missing argument at index 2

(Type 'help test' for related documentation)
bye
```

The only workaround I've found is:

```
if test (git config --get status.showuntrackedfiles; or echo "") = no 
    echo "hi"
else
    echo "bye"
end
```

but it seems hacky. Is there a better way of approaching this?

Comment: This can't be about [tag:bash] if it's about [tag:fish]. Removing the Bash tag.

Answer (score 1):

No less hacky, but here's a way to see if a command substitution returned nothing:

```
set output (git config ...)
if test (count $output) -gt 0 -a $output = no; ...
```

Recall fish variables are lists, so `count` is checking if the list has more then zero elements.